# Spring boot Autowired Service and Repository throwing nullpointerexception

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am testing a simple beginner spring boot application, but it keeps throwing `NullPointerException` for my service class and my repository class.
This is my controller class:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@RestController
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private MyService service;


    @GetMapping("/welcome")
    public String home throws IOException {
        return service.getEntities();
    }

}
```

This is the Service class:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Service
public class MyService{

@Autowired(required=true)
private MyRepository repository;

public MyService() {
};

public List<Entity> getEntities() throws IOException {
        return repository.findAll();
    }
```

And this is the repository:

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<Entity, Long>{

    List<Entity> findAll();

}
```

So, if I run the application everything is ok. The problem is when I run this test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { MyService.class, MyController.class, Entity.class })
@ComponentScan("test.firstproject")
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"test.firstproject.entities"})
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = Replace.NONE)
@EnableJpaRepositories("test.firstproject.repository")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class TestController {

    private MockMvc mvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new MyController).build();

    public static final MediaType APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8 = new MediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.getType(), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.getSubtype(), Charset.forName("utf8"));

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;


    @Test
    public void allEntities() {
        this.objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            ResultActions resultActions = this.mvc
                    .perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/welcome").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
             this.mvc.perform(get("/welcome")).andExpect(status().isOk());
             MvcResult result = resultActions.andReturn();
             List<Object> list = objectMapper.readValue(result.getResponse().getContentAsString(), new TypeReference<List<Entity>>(){});
             for (Object c : list) {
                 assertTrue(c.getClass().equals(Entity.class));
             }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

First, it threw NullPointerException when calling `service.getEntities()`. Then I've tried by initializing the service doing `= new MyService()`, but this time `return repository.findAll();` throws the error. What's wrong?

**EDIT - Stacktrace**

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1013)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:71)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:182)
    at com.example.demo.TestController.getAllEntities(TestController.java:58)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.springmiddleware.controllers.MyController.allEntities(MyController.java:32)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    ... 40 more
```

Comment: Please can you post the stack trace so we can see where the NPE comes from?

Comment: @NotaJD added the stacktrace

Comment: *MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new MyController)* is that valid?

Comment: What is "MyController.allEntities"? I see it in the stacktrace but not in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created MyController using `new` in line:

```
private MockMvc mvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new MyController()).build();
```

Spring probably not injected `Service` to it. Try autowire:

```
@Autowired
private MyController myController;
```

And move `MockMvc` instantiation to `@Before` method:

```
private MockMvc mvc;

@Before
public void initialize() {
    mvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(myController).build();
}
```

Comment: I edited answer, move MockMvc builder in @Before method.